# Custom Field Rollup

Tags: custom-object

We have a custom object called 'Buildings' which has Accounts that are tied under it. How can I create a custom field under Buildings to display the total number of accounts under that building because I would like to show that on a report for penetration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since Accounts can't be on the detail side of a M-D relationship with Buildings, you'll need to create a roll-up trigger that does the roll-up count each time a Building record is edited. There's a [Roll-up Helper managed package](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N30000009i3UpEAI) that's available from the App Exchange or you can get the source code from github at https://github.com/afawcett/declarative-lookup-rollup-summaries.